# I'm trying to deploy an Azure Data Factory service using Azure Resource Manager Templates but getting an error The request content was invalid

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to deploy an Azure Data Factory service using Azure Resource Manager Templates but getting an error The request content was invalid and could not be desterilized:
'Could not find member 'name' on object of type 'Template'. Path 'properties.template.name', line 1, position 34.'.

Comment: Can you please share your template? You can hide the sensitive part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below ARM template for creating a Azure storage account and Azure data factory and linking both of them via linked service:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "metadata": {
    "_generator": {
      "name": "bicep",
      "version": "0.4.1.14562",
      "templateHash": "8367564219536411224"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "dataFactoryName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[format('datafactory{0}', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Data Factory Name"
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location of the data factory."
      }
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[format('storage{0}', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Azure storage account that contains the input/output data."
      }
    },
    "blobContainerName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[format('blob{0}', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the blob container in the Azure Storage account."
      }
    }
  },
  "functions": [],
  "variables": {
    "dataFactoryLinkedServiceName": "ArmtemplateStorageLinkedService",
    "dataFactoryDataSetInName": "ArmtemplateTestDatasetIn",
    "dataFactoryDataSetOutName": "ArmtemplateTestDatasetOut",
    "pipelineName": "ArmtemplateSampleCopyPipeline"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
      "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS"
      },
      "kind": "StorageV2"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
      "name": "[format('{0}/default/{1}', parameters('storageAccountName'), parameters('blobContainerName'))]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
      "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('dataFactoryName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
      "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('dataFactoryName'), variables('dataFactoryLinkedServiceName'))]",
      "properties": {
        "type": "AzureBlobStorage",
        "typeProperties": {
          "connectionString": "[format('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1}', parameters('storageAccountName'), listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), '2021-04-01').keys[0].value)]"
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories', parameters('dataFactoryName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets",
      "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('dataFactoryName'), variables('dataFactoryDataSetInName'))]",
      "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
          "referenceName": "[variables('dataFactoryLinkedServiceName')]",
          "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "type": "Binary",
        "typeProperties": {
          "location": {
            "type": "AzureBlobStorageLocation",
            "container": "[format('{0}/default/{1}', parameters('storageAccountName'), parameters('blobContainerName'))]",
            "folderPath": "input",
            "fileName": "emp.txt"
          }
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers', split(format('{0}/default/{1}', parameters('storageAccountName'), parameters('blobContainerName')), '/')[0], split(format('{0}/default/{1}', parameters('storageAccountName'), parameters('blobContainerName')), '/')[1], split(format('{0}/default/{1}', parameters('storageAccountName'), parameters('blobContainerName')), '/')[2])]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories', parameters('dataFactoryName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices', parameters('dataFactoryName'), variables('dataFactoryLinkedServiceName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets",
      "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('dataFactoryName'), variables('dataFactoryDataSetOutName'))]",
      "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
          "referenceName": "[variables('dataFactoryLinkedServiceName')]",
          "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "type": "Binary",
        "typeProperties": {
          "location": {
            "type": "AzureBlobStorageLocation",
            "container": "[format('{0}/default/{1}', parameters('storageAccountName'), parameters('blobContainerName'))]",
            "folderPath": "output"
          }
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers', split(format('{0}/default/{1}', parameters('storageAccountName'), parameters('blobContainerName')), '/')[0], split(format('{0}/default/{1}', parameters('storageAccountName'), parameters('blobContainerName')), '/')[1], split(format('{0}/default/{1}', parameters('storageAccountName'), parameters('blobContainerName')), '/')[2])]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories', parameters('dataFactoryName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices', parameters('dataFactoryName'), variables('dataFactoryLinkedServiceName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines",
      "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('dataFactoryName'), variables('pipelineName'))]",
      "properties": {
        "activities": [
          {
            "name": "MyCopyActivity",
            "type": "Copy",
            "policy": {
              "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
              "retry": 0,
              "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
              "secureOutput": false,
              "secureInput": false
            },
            "typeProperties": {
              "source": {
                "type": "BinarySource",
                "storeSettings": {
                  "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                  "recursive": true
                }
              },
              "sink": {
                "type": "BinarySink",
                "storeSettings": {
                  "type": "AzureBlobStorageWriterSettings"
                }
              },
              "enableStaging": false
            },
            "inputs": [
              {
                "referenceName": "[variables('dataFactoryDataSetInName')]",
                "type": "DatasetReference"
              }
            ],
            "outputs": [
              {
                "referenceName": "[variables('dataFactoryDataSetOutName')]",
                "type": "DatasetReference"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories', parameters('dataFactoryName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets', parameters('dataFactoryName'), variables('dataFactoryDataSetInName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets', parameters('dataFactoryName'), variables('dataFactoryDataSetOutName'))]"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Reference:**

[Create an Azure Data Factory using an Azure Resource Manager template (ARM template) - Azure Data Factory | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-resource-manager-template)